# When I buy a domain at Godaddy.com (or any other...like hostgator...), who gets the money?

Tags: web-services, hosting

When I buy a domain at Godaddy.com, who gets the money? Is there any .gov website that can register a domain?
I know that Godaddy is a private company, so how come they own all the domain names? If I host my own website using my home computer, then I must be able to register a domain at some US Governmental Website.

**What is the scheme????**

I have a Master's Degree in IT, and this is the question that has been bothering me for a while. My professors were not able to give me a meaningful answer.

Comment: If you have a Master's degree in IT, you should be able to read the [faq] and understand the types of questions that are appropriate to ask here. This isn't one of them. :-) This site is for programming and programmer's tools related questions, and "who gets the money for domain registrations?" isn't either of those. Voting to close as off-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All webpage are registered at icann, the price varies, your private buisness handles the paperwork for you.

Comment: So, can I register my domain directly with icann? Why do I have to go through godaddy, or hostgator...? I have very well do without them. Why do I need to pay them a yearly fee?

Comment: A registration at icann lasts a year (hence the yearly payment), but yes you can go to them directly if you can, and feel like handling the forms yourself. Also please note that icann is non profit, so your not paying for someone to get rich.